# looking for a source that free choice is only prior to our decission

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, free-will-bechira, chazon-ish

I have heard in the name of the chazon ish "לפני מעשה - בידי אדם, לאחר מעשה - בידי שמים".

would be grateful if someone can tell me the most reliable source for this.

Comment: I don't think that what your question suggests is what this saying of the Chazon Ish means. I believe that it means that (in some cases) before a mishap occurs something could have done to avoid it, but after it occurs we say that it was in the hands of heaven.

Comment: @GeminiMan, I suspect that's what the asker may have meant by his title. If, on the contrary, he meant the title literally, that one has no free choice after having already made the choice, then that's obvious: the choice is already made and can't be unmade.

Comment: This sounds like the Ishbitzer. Just spoke with someone about this. I'll try to fin source.

Comment: Reminds me of Tanya, [I.H. #25](http://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7970/jewish/Epistle-25.htm). (Search for the words "This discussion recalls" and a few lines prior).

Comment: Re the title, what's the difference between choice and decision?

Comment: none. ["free choice" is a known concept. and decisions are what we make].

Comment: This question post would be more valuable if it included a translation of the Hebrew phrase, information about where you heard it in the name of the Chazon Ish, and information about why you want to know the most reliable source for it.

Comment: @BabySeal The Izbitzer (parshas Chaye Sara) has what I think is a very much minority opinion, though it seems to be repeated by his student R. Tzadok

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Harav fisher said that on 25th shevat 5755 rebbi shlomo zalman aurbach told him in the name of the chazon ish לפני מעשה בידי אדם לאחר מעשה בידי שמים

literally translated as: before an act - in mans hands; after an act - in Hashems hands.
this is a very deep hashkafic concept and care must e taken to understand it in its correct context.

http://www.kikarhashabat.co.il/%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%90%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9-%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%9D.html

minute 19:54 - in hebrew

Comment: The question asks for sources in the Ch"A's seforim. This answer provides three-ply hearsay, not a citation in seforim. It therefore doesn't address the question. It seems to me that this information would actually work better added to the question, to help substantiate "I heard ..." If you go that route, I recommend that you add in information about who Harav Fisher is, the context of his report to you and/or of his conversation with RSZA, and a translation of the quoted Hebrew.

Comment: hope my edit is satisfactory

Comment: You could make this answer a great deal more valuable by editing in information along the lines of what I listed above. A bare link only goes so far, since it requires a reader to click through and then wade through whatever's on the other side to get the cited information, and the link could die someday. A full citation that identifies who you're quoting and summarizes the information provided that's relevant to the question would make it a great deal easier for readers to use this answer and to determine whether it's worth their time to click the link.

Comment: all the relevent info is "Harav fisher said that on 25th shevat 5755 rebbi shlomo zalman aurbach told him in the name of the chazon ish לפני מעשה בידי אדם לאחר מעשה בידי שמים". - i added the link for those who want to hear it first hand.

Comment: The identity of Harav Fisher is certainly relevant. The contexts of the various levels of reporting are certainly relevant. The identity (not just the bare URL) of whatever it is you linked to is certainly relevant. If you don't have this information, you should acknowledge as much in the answer.

Comment: sorry but i don't know what you want. feel free to do any editing you think will be of benefit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13160/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-rabbi)